# Posso desativar uma div usando css?

Tags: html, css, div

Então, criei duas div uma dentro da outra e minha ideia era seguinte: 
Eu queria deixar uma div inativa, e quando eu deixar o mouse sobre uma, a outra aparece-se.

O comando que eu usei para isso é o opacity: 0; para deixa-la invisível e quando deixo o mouse em cima coloquei o comando opacity: 1; para ela aparecer. 
Só que eu queria somente quando passa-se o mouse sobre a div #botao ela aparece-se.
  Posso fazer isso pelo css?

o codigo é esse:

```css
#botao {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url(../img/wats.jpg);
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
a.botao-link {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#botao:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/wats-hover.jpg);
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
#comentario {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
  left: 30px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
#botao:hover #comentario {
  opacity: 1;
```

```html
<div id="botao"><a href="#" class="wats-link"> botao </a>
  <div id="comentario">Comentário</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar ao invés disso:

```
#botao:hover #comentario {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Isso:

```
#botao a:hover + #comentario {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Assim o hover vai estar no *link* e não na div, como um todo.

Uso o [`seletor +`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) do `css`, para selecionar o elemento em sequência, logo a `div#comentario` deve ser o elemento após o *link*.

Assim, você não "desativa" a `div`, apenas muda o *target* no ´:hover`, do elemento pai (que englobava tanto o *link* quanto o balão), para apena o *link*.

### Demo

```css
#botao {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-image: url(../img/wats.jpg);
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

a.botao-link {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#botao:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/wats-hover.jpg);
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

#comentario {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
  left: 30px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#botao a:hover+#comentario {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="botao">
  <a href="#" class="wats-link"> botao </a>
  <div id="comentario">Comentário</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica.